# Login to Amazon without Browser

Tags: c++, http, curl

I am writing an application in C ++ under Windovs to work with cloud services Amazon. I need to be authorized on the site to work with specific data and I want to get Access Token. The problem is that I want, I get authorization without using a browser, but I can not understand how. I use cURL in the project and send a request that looks like this:

```
int main(void) {
CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;
struct curl_slist *list = NULL;
FILE *Response = fopen("Response.txt", "wb+");
curl = curl_easy_init();
if (curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.amazon.com/ap/oa?client_id=%MY CLIENT ID%scope=clouddrive:read_all&response_type=token&redirect_uri=http://localhost");

    list = curl_slist_append(list, "Accept: text/html");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, list);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, SaveData);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, Response);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);

    /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    /* Check for errors */
    if (res != CURLE_OK) 
        fprintf(Response, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
        curl_easy_strerror(res));


    curl_slist_free_all(list);
    /* always cleanup */
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
```

When I get response I have a copy of the file with HTML Authorization Page. /*Below is a part of the answer*/

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">
    <html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">
 
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>var ue_t0=ue_t0||+new Date();</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var ue_csm = window,
    ue_hob = +new Date();
```

If I can not use the browser, while I can open a small window with a Web browser (no frame) and to receive data from the server (Access Token). There is nothing in the documents it (Amazon Documentation).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make you application "talk" to AWS, you are supposed to use their APIs, and not the web console. API requests are stateless and [signed with credentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signing_aws_api_requests.html), and don't depend on authentication sessions like the web console.

They have official SDKs for many popular languages, but not for C++, unfortunately. So, unless you find one somewhere, you'll have to implement your own client(s), but it's all HTTP(S)-based.

Another thing worth to mention is that every product has a separate and independent API (*[EC2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/Query-Requests.html)*, *[S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/APIRest.html)*, *[RDS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html)*, etc). As far as I know, you won't find an all-in-one API for all AWS products. Documentation may be a bit sparse too, but most products are well-covered.

Good luck. ;)